# couldn't verify crypt-sha-512 password after ldapadd

Tags: python, bash, openldap, sha512, apache-directory

I'm writing a script in bash that generates LDIF file(for user account) and loads it to LDAP via ldapadd.
The issue is in encrypting password to CRYPT-SHA-512. I'm using python for it.

```
password=`python3 -c 'import crypt; print(crypt.crypt("$pass", crypt.mksalt(crypt.METHOD_SHA512)))'`
```

But every time after script importing that LDIF I cannot verify that password via [Apache Directory Studio(screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gswnf.png).

For example, if I'm encrypting "xaPa3Ait" script returns:
`{CRYPT}$6$le2gfSxoFUZD2aqn$mTJby4dsvRGHINkGVacFXido0V3WIZ3mmOod3viIIyoV8sXrQOp4Dk.H8wkOpWUTmQ0XWJ8j9Lpz8No.R/CEJ.`
And it cannot be verified in Directory studio as well.

I can admit that I'm not the best programmer and there could be better ways to encrypt passwords, so your advice will be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a bit easier method using mkpasswd which worked perfectly after password check in Apache Directory Studio:
password=`mkpasswd -m sha-512 --salt $salt $password`

JFR, here are: 
 1. salt generation command(install pwgen):

```
salt=`pwgen 50 1 | cut -b 10-25`
```

2. converting the password to base64 and deleting simultaneously appearing whitespace:

```
password=$(echo -n "$password" | base64)
password=$(echo $password | tr -d ' ')
```